# Passing Request data into a model observer class

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, observer-pattern, observers

I have the following Model Observer:

```
class UserObserver {
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * UserObserver constructor.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * User created
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        try {
            // Create the user's first profile for them.
            $profile = $user->profiles()->create([ 'name' => $this->request->get('username'), 'description' => null ]);

            // Set the users active profile to the one just created.
            $user->active_profile = $profile->id;
            $user->save();

        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a users table seeder which sets a new request:

```
 $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
 $request->replace(['username' => $user['username']]);
```

At the moment, when the seeder is being run the request is being set and this has been verified as working within the seeder class, however, once it is getting to the Model Observer the request is empty(null).

What I am trying to achieve is when a new user is created then a new profile is created for the user based and I would like this profile to have the name that the user has entered in to the form but also work when the seeder is being run.

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: You've tied your observer class to a specific front end implementation and tried to make up for it by spoofing an http request from your seeder.  imo, a design evaluation is in order instead of figuring out how to better fake the request and make your changes persist in it.

Comment: You're trying this `$this->request->get('username')`, but doesn't the user have the `username` as an attribute, does it?

Comment: @dacastro4 No it doesn't, if I attempt to set $user->username, it will throw an error as the username column doesn't exist on the user. It exists on the profile. 

When a new user is created I want to be able to create a new profile too.

Comment: What if on the seeder you create a new request? And instead of using the regular request, you use the global method `request()`?